# Collision of objects in orbit around Earth

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, collision

I'm doing a risk assessment of space debris in low Earth Orbit (about $1000-2000$ kms). While working on a simplified model, I couldn't correctly predict the outcome of a random collision, so far we've only dealt with $1$-Dimensional collisions in our curriculum.

Let us suppose object $1$ collides with object $2$, they are on different intersecting elliptical orbits.
Trying to do the resulting calculations, I've struggled with the following points :

> i) Is momentum conserved ?

My answer is no, as the velocities are not necessarily orthoradial and we cannot therefore neglect gravitational pull. 
Edit: this seems to be a silly question, since the net external force is not zero, so the answer is definitely no.
so will the loss of the resulting equation make calculations impossible?

> ii) Can the collisions be approximated by elastic collisions?

I think we safely assume that the collisions are elastic, as there is no air friction and the relative velocities are extremely high (in general).

Comment: You want to solve iv) first, similar for the momentum. Then you can say whether your collisions will be elastic to a high degree or not.

Comment: I've reduced the question to only include i and ii.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collisions often happen over very small timeframes, creating huge forces.  In such cases, we can often ignore the contributions from smaller forces.

For a collision at orbital velocities, the effect of earth's gravity over a period of a few milliseconds is nearly inconsequential.  Any modeling of the collision could be done by assuming momentum is conserved, and then later see what gravity does to the products of the collision.

Anything that deforms is going to have inelastic losses.  A complex device that shatters internally is going to have inelastic losses.   All of the energy required to rip pieces off removes mechanical energy from the system.  Whether those are significant or not depends on your model.  The higher the energy of the collision, the smaller a fraction those losses will be to the total energy.